# "...time to for what he wants to do..."

Tags: grammar

I came into this sentence while reading a newspaper.
Although I think it's a simple mistake overlooked by the writer, 
I'd like to have a confirmation by a native speaker.

"The prince, who five years ago proposed a retirement age for
emperors, said he hoped his father would have time **to for** what
he wants to do, such as research of gobioid fish and music."

Have a good day

Comment: Either *time to do what he wants to do* or *time for what he wants to do*.

Comment: It's a typo.  Hard to say for sure, but probably the "to" is extraneous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## to for

Typographical error.

## onto, into, hitherto

Acceptable forms. This compound is the English way of expressing motion in a direction.

e.g.

```
[...] onto the platform
[...] into the bag
```